# SQL Performing a select as a column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have some doubts about a sql code i'm trying to run. First of all I have 2 tables that are out of discussion:

**course**

- id_course
- name_course
- date_begin
- date_finish
- number_students_enrolled

**students_course**

- id_student
- id_course
- state

I need to perform a select of the "course" table but also I have to count rows in "students_course" and add the result to the "number_students_enrolled" column if it corresponds to the same course and the state is equal to 3. I don't know how to combine the select statement and add the result to the first table.

Example, I have a course with 9 students enrolled, but in the "students_course" table exists another 3 rows that belong to the same course id and also it state is equal to 3, so I have to count it and then add it to the number_students_enrolled column and show the final result, in this case it will be 12. Can you help me to try to solve this? Thank you!

Some sample data:

course

```
id_course - name_course - date_begin - date_finish - number_students_enrolled
  150     -    maths    -   02/10/16 -   04/10/16  -          9
  172     -    economy  -   02/14/16 -   05/08/16  -          21
```

students_course

```
id_student - id_course - state
  10       -    150    -  3
  12       -    150    -  3
  13       -    150    -  3
  14       -    150    -  1
  15       -    194    -  2
  16       -    194    -  3
```

After the select I have to obtain the following result

```
id_course - name_course - date_begin - date_finish - number_students_enrolled
  150     -    maths    -   02/10/16 -   04/10/16  -          12
  172     -    economy  -   02/14/16 -   05/08/16  -          21
```

Comment: I think you should show us some sample data so we don't spend time under the wrong assumptions.

Comment: This seems like a pretty basic `join` with aggregation.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, I added some sample data to help you to understand my problem. Sorry for the text format, this is my first time here and I'm learning how to use it.

Comment: Isn't the column `number_students_enrolled` already present in `course` table? Are you trying to insert into `course` table?

Comment: I'm REALLY curious as to what course you are doing because this is the third identical question I've seen in two days.

Comment: Yes, it is already present but it is harcoded and I'm not trying to insert into `course` table, just add the count number of `students_course` to the `number_students_enrolled` and show it by a query.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT c.name_course,c.number_students_enrolled+(SELECT count(sc2.id_student)
FROM dbo.students_course sc2    WHERE sc2.id_course=c.id_course 
AND sc2.state   =3) FROM dbo.course c
```

Answer (score 0):

Not considering that you have *number_students_enrolled* column already, I'm giving you a query. Hope it helps.

```
  select C.id_course, C.name_course, 
         (select count(1) 
            from students_course 
           where id_course = C.ID 
             and state = 3) as call_as_you_need_this_column
    from course C
order by C.id_course
```

It is just a one way to reach what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This query is going to give you the number of students enrolled:

```
select c.id_course, count(*) as students_enrolled
from course c join student_course sc on c.id_course = sc.id_course
group by id_course;
```

[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc928c/1)

if you want it to to be "pre-calculated, i would suggest a view.

Answer (score 0):

try this query to get result

```
  SELECT c.id_course,c.name_course,c.date_begin,c.date_finish,
   (NVL(temp.cnt, 0)+c.number_students_enrolled)
   FROM course c   
   left join (SELECT count(sc.id_student) as cnt,sc.id_course as course_id
   FROM students_course sc  WHERE sc.state   =3 group by sc.id_course ) as temp 
   on temp.course_id =c.id_course
```